# Adding legend to a radarchart in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, legend, seaborn

I want to create a radarchart with legends for every plot that is created but until now it has been impossible. Then, you can see the code used to create the plot (thanks to another user that developed it).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns # improves plot aesthetics
import pandas as pd

def _invert(x, limits):
    """inverts a value x on a scale from
    limits[0] to limits[1]"""
    return limits[1] - (x - limits[0])

def _scale_data(data, ranges):
    """scales data[1:] to ranges[0],
    inverts if the scale is reversed"""
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        assert (y1 <= d <= y2) or (y2 <= d <= y1)
    x1, x2 = ranges[0]
    d = data[0]
    if x1 > x2:
        d = _invert(d, (x1, x2))
        x1, x2 = x2, x1
    sdata = [d]
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        if y1 > y2:
            d = _invert(d, (y1, y2))
            y1, y2 = y2, y1
        sdata.append((d-y1) / (y2-y1) 
                     * (x2 - x1) + x1)
    return sdata

class ComplexRadar():
    def __init__(self, fig, variables, ranges,
                 n_ordinate_levels=6):
        angles = np.arange(0, 360, 360./len(variables))

        axes = [fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9],polar=True,
                label = "axes{}".format(i)) 
                for i in range(len(variables))]
        l, text = axes[0].set_thetagrids(angles, 
                                         labels=variables)
        [txt.set_rotation(angle-90) for txt, angle 
             in zip(text, angles)]
        for ax in axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
            grid = np.linspace(*ranges[i], 
                               num=n_ordinate_levels)
            gridlabel = ["{}".format(round(x,2)) 
                         for x in grid]
            if ranges[i][0] > ranges[i][1]:
                grid = grid[::-1] # hack to invert grid
                          # gridlabels aren't reversed
            gridlabel[0] = "" # clean up origin
            ax.set_rgrids(grid, labels=gridlabel,
                         angle=angles[i])
            #ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_ylim(*ranges[i])
        # variables for plotting
        self.angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[angles, angles[0]])
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.ax = axes[0]
    def plot(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.plot(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)
    def fill(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.fill(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)
```

Every plot represents to different people. I want to add a legend showing the name of everyone and the color that represents him in the plot. I tried to add labels and then the legends but it didn´t work. The plot produced is something like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Spe": pd.Series([89, 83, 70, 60, 30, 49, 28]),
    "Str": pd.Series([69, 53, 30, 20, 10, 29, 48]),
    "Det": pd.Series([82, 44, 79, 39, 20, 10, 85]),
    "Extr": pd.Series([59, 74, 29, 36, 18, 29, 18]),
    "Int": pd.Series([63, 11, 20, 36, 97, 58, 91]),
    "Est": pd.Series([12, 69, 89, 59, 19, 58, 98]),
    "Ape": pd.Series([29, 13, 94, 30, 20, 10, 67]),
    "ID": pd.Series(["Carl","Michael","Peter","Louis","Sarah",
                    "Laura","Nicholas"])
})
dfo = df.drop('ID', 1)
print(dfo)

variables = ("1", "2", "3", 
        "4", "5", "6", "7")
ranges = [(1,100),(1,100),(1,100),(1,100),(1,100),(1,100),(1,100)] 
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
radar = ComplexRadar(fig1, variables, ranges)
for i in range(len(dfo.index)-1):
    data=dfo.iloc[i,:]
    radar.plot(data)
    radar.fill(data,alpha=0.2)
sns.plt.show()
```

[Link to plot produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiK1Q.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is interested, the code of the `ComplexRadar` comes from [here](https://gist.github.com/kylerbrown/29ce940165b22b8f25f4).
The `ComplexRadar` class uses many axes and makes all of them invisible, so the best way to create a legend here, would be to create a new axes to put the legend in. For that we need the handles of the plotted lines, so we need to change the `ComplexRadar.plot()` method to return the line. We then need to collect those lines in a list (call it `lax`) and supply them to the new legend.

I did make some changes to the code to make it work in python 2.7 and also to make it more comprehensible to myself. Here is, what should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 
import pandas as pd

def _scale_data(data, ranges):
    """scales data[1:] to ranges[0],
    """
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        assert (y1 <= d <= y2) or (y2 <= d <= y1)
    x1, x2 = ranges[0]
    d = data[0]
    sdata = [d]
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        sdata.append((d-y1) / (y2-y1) 
                     * (x2 - x1) + x1)
    return sdata

class ComplexRadar():
    def __init__(self, fig, variables, ranges,
                 n_ordinate_levels=6):
        angles = np.arange(0, 360, 360./len(variables))

        axes = [fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9],polar=True,
                label = "axes{}".format(i)) 
                for i in range(len(variables))]
        l, text = axes[0].set_thetagrids(angles, 
                                         labels=variables)
        [txt.set_rotation(angle-90) for txt, angle 
             in zip(text, angles)]
        for ax in axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
            grid = np.linspace(*ranges[i], 
                               num=n_ordinate_levels)
            gridlabel = ["{}".format(round(x,2)) 
                         for x in grid]
            if ranges[i][0] > ranges[i][1]:
                grid = grid[::-1] # hack to invert grid
                          # gridlabels aren't reversed
            gridlabel[0] = "" # clean up origin
            ax.set_rgrids(grid, labels=gridlabel,
                         angle=angles[i])
            #ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_ylim(*ranges[i])
        # variables for plotting
        self.angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[angles, angles[0]])
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.ax = axes[0]

    def plot(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        l = self.ax.plot(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)
        return l

    def fill(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.fill(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)



index = ["Carl","Michael","Peter","Louis","Sarah", "Laura","Nicholas"]      
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Spe": pd.Series([89, 83, 70, 60, 30, 49, 28]),
    "Str": pd.Series([69, 53, 30, 20, 10, 29, 48]),
    "Det": pd.Series([82, 44, 79, 39, 20, 10, 85]),
    "Extr": pd.Series([59, 74, 29, 36, 18, 29, 18]),
    "Int": pd.Series([63, 11, 20, 36, 97, 58, 91]),
    "Est": pd.Series([12, 69, 89, 59, 19, 58, 98]),
    "Ape": pd.Series([29, 13, 94, 30, 20, 10, 67]),
})

variables = [k[0] for k in df.iteritems()]

ranges = [(1.,100.),(1.,100.),(1.,100.),(1.,100.),(1.,100.),(1.,100.),(1.,100.)] 
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
radar = ComplexRadar(fig1, variables, ranges)
lax = []
for i, name  in enumerate(index):
    data=df.iloc[i].values
    l, = radar.plot(data, label=name)
    lax.append(l)
    radar.fill(data,alpha=0.2)

legendax = fig1.add_axes([0.8,0.8,0.1,.1])
legendax.legend(handles = lax, labels=index, loc=3, bbox_to_anchor=(0,0,1,1), bbox_transform=fig1.transFigure )

legendax.axis('off')
sns.plt.show()
```

producing the following plot
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe do you know what I have to do to transform the code to JS? I am trying to use Bokeh, but when it shows me the HTML version of the plot, it´s just a void figure.

Comment: I guess the question how to make this work in bokeh is a different one. You may want to file a new question about that, showing your bokeh code. I am not an expert in bokeh, so I think I cannot help, but someone else may.

Comment: Ok, I´ll do it. Last question (I´m sorry for being so annoying, but I´m learning Python yet), in this case how can I change the colors? I´ve been trying to add the sns.color_palette() in different sites of the code but it haven´t worked.