# How to add legend to Radar chart in Python

Tags: python, charts, legend

I would like to add a legend to the Radar chart. That shows score changes over time.Sp I want each line in the chart to be categorized based on a specific date.

The code is as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

categories = ['GAD-7','PHQ-9','Likert-Insomnia','Likert-Depression','Likert-Anxiety']

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=Survey['GAD7Score'],
      theta=categories,
      #fill='toself',
      name='GAD-7'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=Survey['PHQ9Score'],
      theta=categories,
      #fill='toself',
      name='PHQ-9'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=Survey['Likert-Insomnia'],
      theta=categories,
      #fill='toself',
      name='Likert-Insomnia'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=Survey['Likert-Depression'],
      theta=categories,
      #fill='toself',
      name='Likert-Depression'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=Survey['Likert-Anxiety'],
      theta=categories,
      #fill='toself',
      name='Likert-Anxiety'
     
))


fig.update_layout(
  polar=dict(
    radialaxis=dict(
      visible=True,
      range=[0, 7]
    )),
  showlegend=True
)


fig.show()
```

The displayed figure gives the legend for the categories while the legend should be the date column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckpF9.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208035/adding-legend-to-a-radarchart-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding legend to a radarchart in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208035/adding-legend-to-a-radarchart-in-python)